# Vector Surface Integrals of a Cylinder (with a shortcut)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, surface-integrals

I'm struggling with this question in my book. It wants me to find the surface integral

$$\iint_s F \cdot n \,dS.$$

It also says that I can observe something about the object to make it far less computationally intensive.

I am given $F = (x\ln(x^2+y^2),y\ln(x^2+y^2),0)$ and the [the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmCQT.png).

The answer that I am supposed to receive is $4\pi R^2 h \ln(R)$.

Here is the work that I have done, but it never seems to work out to the right answer.

I observe that there is no force in the $\hat k$ direction and therefore the top and the bottom of the cylinder are irrelevant.

I then move on to set up the integral of the cylindrical surface without a top and bottom.

I determine the normal to be $(2x,2y,1)$ using the formula for the cylinder $x^2+y^2=R^2$.

Then dotting this and plugging it into the integral I get

$$\iint 2x^2\ln(x^2+y^2)+2y^2\ln(x^2+y^2)\, dA.$$

I then convert these into cylindrical coordinates to get

$$2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r r^3cos^2(\theta)\ln(r^2)+r^3sin^2(\theta)\ln(r^2) \,drd\theta.$$

Pulling out constants I get

$$2r^2\ln(r^2)\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r r \,dA.$$

This evaluates to $4(\pi)^2r^2\ln(r^2)$, which is nowhere close to the right answer provided above. I am confused where I went wrong or what I am missing about the problem. I know I need $h$, but I don't know how this would factor into the equation at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are integrating over the top or bottom disc. You should integrate over the cylinder mantle, which can be parametrized by
$$
   \Sigma(\theta, z) = (R\cos\theta, R\sin \theta, z)
$$
with $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ and $z \in [0,h]$. The normal is $n(\theta,z) = (R\cos \theta, R\sin \theta, 0)$. Also
$$
  F(\Sigma(\theta,z)) = (R\cos\theta \ln R^2, R\sin\theta\ln R^2,0),
$$
so the integrand becomes $F(\Sigma(\theta,z))\cdot n(\theta,z) = R^2 \ln R^2 = 2R^2 \ln R$. 
Integrating this over the mantle is easy since it's constant w.r.t. to $\theta$ and $z$. The integral is $2\pi h (2R^2 \ln R)$, which is the answer.